# how to setup selenium php with chrome webdriver in server using cpanel?

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, facebook-php-webdriver

i am trying to setup selenium php with chrome driver in cpanel. i already installed chrome browser and chrome webdriver and also installed php-webdriver library "https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver" but it not working. when i execute script it showing page is not working error. can any one help me to setup php selenium in shared hosting server or cpanel? below is selenium script

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver; 
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities; 
use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverBy;
$capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome(); 
$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create('http://localhost:4444', $capabilities);
```